# What does the end of Kim Stanley Robinson's "Our Town" mean?

Tags: kim-stanley-robinson

Could someone explain to me the ending of Kim Stanley Robinson's short story ["Our Town"](http://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/our-town/)?

Comment: It's not the play. It's a short story by a well known science fiction author. Clicking the link gives the full text, which feels like science fiction to me.

Comment: Oh...that's why I was confused. Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desmond is going to jump off the edge of the city into the world below. He has a parachute  ("the purposefully rectangular package strapped to his back"), however, so Roarick knows that he's not attempting suicide but instead wants to "Heal the sick, or … give advice about agricultural practices. … or just put one more shoulder to the wheel! Add one more hand to tend that fire!" As for Roarick and the girl, we have no idea if they escape via "the closer greenhouse door".